# Recordings of fluently spoken Esperanto?

Tags: learning, resources, speaking

Where can one find recordings of fluently spoken Esperanto (conversations, podcasts, audio books...), where the speaker commands the language with the speed and ease of a first language speaker?

Comment: You could check this https://player.fm/podcasts/esperanto for example. There are lots of other sources though. Here for example you have a young native speaker teaching how to solve the Rubik cube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w62ameHzDlo Do a serach for "intervjuoj" or "podkastoj", maybe tack "esperanto" to the search and you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the podcast [Denaskulo: Kreski kun Esperanto](https://anchor.fm/stela-besenyei-merger). The creator is a native Esperanto speaker and she interviews other native speakers as well. She speaks very naturally.

Answer (score 1):

From that good list Eduardo gave I would like to lift up:

### [Pola retradio](http://pola-retradio.org)

- elsendas dufoje semajne intervjuojn, novaĵojn pri kulturo, scienco ktp.
- klara, kelkfoje ete malmoderna stilo

### [Kern.punkto](https://kern.punkto.info)

- elsendas unu- aŭ dufoje monate intervjuojn, raportaĵojn pri sciencaj, socialaj kaj politikaj temoj
- la lingva stilo estas klara, sed depende de la temo vi povas havi malfaĉilaĵojn por kompreni

Note also

### [El Popola Ĉinio](http://www.espero.com.cn)

- elsendas tagnokte novaĵojn, raportaĵojn
- klara stilo, sed multaj rigardas de temp' al temp' tro propaganda

Answer (score 1):

Also Radio Vatikana three times a week:
Podcasts: https://www.vaticannews.va/eo/podcast/esperanto-programo.html
Archive with summaries: http://www.radio-vatikana-esperanto.org/

Worth noting: https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto-radio

Answer (score 1):

Jen estas ekzemplo - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8wecSB93wO94hX4d96NZWA - ŝi komencis studi esperanton, se mi memoras, nur antaŭ unu jaro aŭ eĉ malpli ol jaro. Kiam oni anoncis la kvarantenon. Chelsea estas nia nova stelulo .)
Jen tio - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmkhn3JfgRGeLfRMVa9yUvQ - estas jam iomete malnova kolekto de babilado. Tamen Evildea estas pioniro.

Answer (score 1):

In this YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OArF83_6Qw) , actor Alex Miller performs the "to be or not to be" soliloquy from Hamlet in Esperanto, as translated in 1894 by Dr Zamenhof.  From there, I subscribed to Alex Millers' YouTube channel, Exploring Esperanto, which has Esperanto lessons, lectures, audiobooks, poetry, and songs.